# Extract strings for localization from a class in Angular

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, ivy

I'm using Angular 12 for a current project. I'd like to translate some string from inside a code file (*.ts) using the built-in feature of Angular.
Looking in the documentation, there is a function called ***$locale*** that accepts a string template that is used for the translation. This function is used inside code of a component.
In my case i use the ***$locale*** function inside a class that represents my model.
But when I use the `ng extract-i18n` command to extract the string and build the ***messages.xlf*** file I don't see my extracted labels.
I'd like to know if there is any configuration to use ***$locale*** inside non component class.

Comment: The function is `$localize \`string\``

Comment: Nevermind. The module was dynamically loaded at runtime using the angular.json file. So using the production mode that is the same of build, the module was changed by an empty one. Anyway thanks.